What would be some effective ways of bringing through the details of the layer below?
I have the below image, it's very hi-res and I need to set a headline on it (see below). What would be the best way to being some of these details, like the smokiness and specs of paint above the headline.
I was thinking that adding a layer mask to the headline then painting the image in, but was wondering if there was something more effective that allows me to make a better selection for masking.
To be clear, I'm looking for a few suggestions to be more precise and efficient.



Here is a very simple idea-
Set the Type Layer's Blend mode to Overlay. You can play with the Opacity slider to your liking as well.
This is white type with the Overlay Blend mode at 100% Opacity

